# System.IO.FileNotFoundException System can't find specified file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I'm making a mod for a game in VS. I added a reference to TagLibSharp and it works fine in VS but when I run the game, even if the code is in an if statement that doesn't run but references TagLibSharp, it gives the error.

I don't know if the problem is related to how the game is built or some other thing. I'm not the most experienced coder either, having only made mods for this game.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'TagLibSharp, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db62eba44689b5b0' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
> Nombre de archivo: 'TagLibSharp, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db62eba44689b5b0'

Fusion Log:

> ```
>   FusionLog   "=== Información de estado anterior al enlace ===\r\nLOG: DisplayName = TagLibSharp, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db62eba44689b5b0\n (Fully-specified)\r\nLOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Duck Game/\r\nLOG: PrivatePath inicial = NULL\r\nEnsamblado de llamada : (Unknown).\r\n===\r\nLOG: Este enlace empieza en el contexto de carga default.\r\nLOG: Utilización del archivo de configuración de la aplicación: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Duck Game\\DuckGame.exe.Config\r\nLOG: Utilizando el archivo de configuración de host: \r\nLOG: Utilizando el archivo de configuración del equipo en C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\config\\machine.config.\r\nLOG: Referencia posterior a la directiva: TagLibSharp, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db62eba44689b5b0\r\nLOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Duck Game/TagLibSharp.DLL.\r\nLOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Duck Game/TagLibSharp/TagLibSharp.DLL.\r\nLOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Duck Game/TagLibSharp.EXE.\r\nLOG: Intento de descarga de la nueva dirección URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Duck Game/TagLibSharp/TagLibSharp.EXE.\r\n"   string
> ```

Comment: Check the exception's `FusionLog` property, what is written there?

Comment: The solution to this is going to depend on the specific game. It's likely you need to deploy your assembly in a different location-- possibly the folder that contains the game itself, or some other folder in its [probing path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location). If there isn't any documentation for this, checking the [fusion logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) is a good place to start.

Comment: I don't know what is going on in the Fusion Log, but there it is.

Comment: Looks like moving the .dll to the game's folder is all I needed. Thanks for the help!